# Regex in JavaScript to process a URL

Tags: javascript, html, regex, regex-group

I am trying to write regex to match below of array words in page URL

e.g. 
array = [schools,years,school,year,school-class,school-year,school-class-year,school-year-class,year-school, year-school-class]

Page url pattern

```
http://www.google.com/search.html/{PATTERN}{/optional_String}
```

Regex required for

```
http://www.google.com/search.html/schools
http://www.google.com/search.html/years
http://www.google.com/search.html/year/2017
http://www.google.com/search.html/school/honda
https://www.google.com/search.html/year-school/2017/thomas
http://www.google.com/search.html/school-class/thomas/ClassA
http://www.google.com/search.html/school-year/thomas/2017
http://www.google.com/search.html/year-school-class/2017/thomas/ClassA
http://www.google.com/search.html/school-class-year/thomas/ClassA/2017
http://www.google.com/search.html/school-year-class/thomas/2017/ClassA
```

I am new to regex, have tried below but failed in many test case.

```
/(http|https):\/\/([\w\-\.]+)\/search.html\/(schools|years|school|year)|(school|year)-?(school|year|class)?-?(school|year|class)?-?(school|year|class)/g
```

Comment: Have you tried any online regex editor? I personally use https://regex101.com/ , give it a try.

Comment: Does it help if you parenthesize your `|` operator?

Comment: @pratibha I am using the same.

Comment: @DavisHerring where exactly I have to parenthesize.

Comment: Around any `|` that you don't want to divide the entire RE into alternatives?

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: @Firanolfind yes I have resolved now. But also, I have seen if url is like /year-school-class/2014 - in that case no result is there because school and class is not in url.

Comment: Try to prepare separete patterns for each case, and iterate through them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Suggestion

I suggest you to try nice lib [**url-pattern**](https://github.com/snd/url-pattern)

```
var pattern = new UrlPattern('/year-school-class/:year/:school/:class');

var url = 'http://www.google.com/search.html/school-year-class/thomas/2017/ClassA'
var path = url.replace('www.google.com/search.html', '')
              .replace(/^\/\/|^.*?:(\/\/)?/, '');
// "/school-year-class/thomas/2017/ClassA"

pattern.match(path);
// {year: '2017', school: 'thomas', class: 'ClassA'}
```

### Without third party libraries

If you not allowed to use 3rd party libraries check this simple class with similar usage. Class constructor creates pattern, and match method returns results, if path does not match it returns `null`. Basic logic I extracted from [Backbone.Router](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-195). Credits to Backbone team.

[**JSBin Sample**](https://jsbin.com/ririceqapo/1/edit?js,console)

**Usage**

```
var pattern = '/year-school-class/:year/:school/:class(/:optional)';
var url = 'http://www.google.com/search.html/year-school-class/2017/thomas/ClassA'
//extract path
var path = url.replace('www.google.com/search.html', '')
              .replace(/^\/\/|^.*?:(\/\/)?/, '');
// "/school-year-class/thomas/2017/ClassA/"

var pattern = new PathPattern(pattern);
var params = pattern.match(path);
console.log(params);
// {year: '2017', school: 'thomas', class: 'ClassA', optional: null}

var params = pattern.match(path + '/someOptionalStuff');
console.log(params);
// {year: '2017', school: 'thomas', class: 'ClassA', optional: 'someOptionalStuff'}
```

**Class source code**

```
class PathPattern{
  constructor(pattern){
    this.keys = [];
    var optionalParam = /\((.*?)\)/g;
    var namedParam    = /(\(\?)?:\w+/g;
    var splatParam    = /\*\w+/g;
    var escapeRegExp  = /[\-{}\[\]+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g;
    var route = pattern.replace(escapeRegExp, '\\$&')
                   .replace(optionalParam, '(?:$1)?')
                   .replace(namedParam, (match, optional) => {
                     if(!optional)
                         this.keys.push(match.replace(/:/,''))
                     return optional ? match : '([^/?]+)';
                   })
                   .replace(splatParam, '([^?]*?)');
    this.rgx = new RegExp('^' + route + '(?:\\?([\\s\\S]*))?$');
  }
  match(path){
    var params = {};
    var values = this.rgx.exec(path);
    if(!values) return null;
    values = values.slice(1);
    values = values.map((param, i)=>{
       if (i === values.length - 1) return param || null;
       return param ? decodeURIComponent(param) : null;
    });
    this.keys.forEach((key, i)=> params[key] = values[i]);
    return params;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @firanolfind, It's strict instruction for us, not to use any 3rd party library.

Comment: Nice answer. It looks like `url-pattern` is very similar to how [`express`](https://expressjs.com/) works under-the-hood. For the record, express uses [`path-to-regexp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) instead.

Comment: Thanks, @Firanolfind.